# JPQL Queries only work within @Query annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I made a class to extend my Repository, because I need a more dynamic query for one of my methods.

The classes and interfaces look like this:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentEntity, Long>, IStudentRepository {
}

interface IStudentRepository {
    List<StudentEntity> getFiltered();
}

class StudentRepositoryImpl implements IStudentRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<StudentEntity> getFiltered() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM StudentEntity s", StudentEntity.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

The query always returns an empty list. If I instead choose to create a native query or if I write the query inside a @Query annotation on a method than everything works fine.

What causes it to fail (silently) inside the separate class?

Comment: What is the entity class called, `Student` or `StudentEntity` (as you're using both)? Are there any warnings in the logs?

Comment: My bad, it's called `StudentEntity`. I updated the question. The only warning I see is `WARN 9860 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning` which I think is unrelated.

Comment: How do the `StudentEntity` instances get into the table? Does the method actually get executed?

Comment: Yes, the method does get executed. If I replace the createQuery with a createNativeQuery it works, but I would like to avoid that and instead figure out why it fails. The table table is populated with repository.save() calls before.